# Making a function to return X amount of rows from table with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, mysqli

I am new to functions so to learn about them I have been converting a website I made to use functions. I want to be able to use the function for other sites, so I am hoping to pass all the table/query information to the function, then return the posts in arrays or something similar so I can style them however needed once the function has passed the info back. I have achieved this with a single post, but can't get it to work with multiple posts. I will usually be retreiving about 10 rows, at the moment with 4 columns.

Here is my single post function

```
   function readPostByID($postID, $table) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM '$table' WHERE id = '$postID'")) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $time1 = date('H:i \o\n jS M Y', $row['publishedtime']);
            $postarray['1'] = $row['title'];
            $postarray['2'] = $row['content'];
            $postarray['3'] = $row['author'];
            $postarray['4'] = $time1;
        }
        $result->close();
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return $postarray;
}
```

Any help to switching this to retreive multiple posts would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: create a function with offset, limit arguments and change the query to limit the rows..!

Answer (score 0):

The first change would be to select a range of ids, which you can do like this:

```
 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

You're already looping across the results, but you'll need a better data structure to store them in.

The other suggestions to use `LIMIT` and offset are good if you're doing paging.